# How to get pair-wise "sequence similarity score" for ~1000 proteins?

Tags: r, sequence, similarity

I have a large number of protein sequences in fasta format.

I want to get the pair-wise sequence similarity score for each pairs of the proteins.

Any package in R could be used to get the blast similarity score for protein sequences?

Comment: Are you familiar with [bioconductor](http://www.bioconductor.org/)? I know nothing about proteins, fasta formats, or pair-wise sequence similarity scores - but that'd be where I'd go to look.

Comment: Thank you Chase for introduction to Bioconductor.  It am new to it.  Thanks Gavin Simpson for editing my poor English.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As per Chase's suggestion, `bioconductor` is indeed the way to go and in particular the `Biostrings` package. To install the latter I would suggest installing the core `bioconductor` library as such:

```
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite()
```

This way you will cover all dependencies. Now, to align 2 protein sequences or any two sequences for that matter you will need to use `pairwiseAlignment` from `Biostrings`. Given a fasta `protseq.fasta` file of 2 sequences that looks like this:

```
>protein1
MYRALRLLARSRPLVRAPAAALASAPGLGGAAVPSFWPPNAAR
MASQNSFRIEYDTFGELKVPNDKYYGAQTVRSTMNFKIGGVTE
RMPTPVIKAFGILKRAAAEVNQDYGLDPKIANAIMKAADEVAE
GKLNDHFPLVVWQTGSGTQTNMNVNEVISNRAIEMLGGELGSK
IPVHPNDHVNKSQ
>protein2
MRSRPAGPALLLLLLFLGAAESVRRAQPPRRYTPDWPSLDSRP
LPAWFDEAKFGVFIHWGVFSVPAWGSEWFWWHWQGEGRPYQRF
MRDNYPPGFSYADFGPQFTARFFHPEEWADLFQAAGAKYVVLT
TKHHEGFTNW*
```

If you want to globally align these 2 sequences using lets say BLOSUM100 as your substitution matrix, 0 penalty for opening a gap and -5 for extending one then:

```
require("Biostrings")
data(BLOSUM100)
seqs <- readFASTA("~/Desktop/protseq.fasta", strip.descs=TRUE)
alm <- pairwiseAlignment(seqs[[1]]$seq, seqs[[2]]$seq, substitutionMatrix=BLOSUM100, gapOpening=0, gapExtension=-5)
```

The result of this is (removed some of the alignment to save space):

```
> alm
Global PairwiseAlignedFixedSubject (1 of 1)
pattern: [1] MYRALRLLARSRPLVRA-PAAALAS....
subject: [1] M-R-------SRP---AGPALLLLL.... 
score: -91
```

To only extract the score for each alignment:

```
> score(alm)
[1] -91
```

Given this you can easily now do all pairwise alignments with some very simple looping logic. To get a better hang of pairwise alignment using `bioconductor` I suggest you read [this](http://bioconductor.org/packages/2.6/bioc/vignettes/Biostrings/inst/doc/Alignments.pdf).

An alternative approach would be to do a multiple sequence alignment instead of pairwise. You could use [bio3d](http://mccammon.ucsd.edu/~bgrant/bio3d/index.html) and from there the [seqaln](http://mccammon.ucsd.edu/~bgrant/bio3d/html/seqaln.html) function to align all sequences in your fasta file.

Answer (score 3):

6 years later, but:

The [`protr`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/protr/vignettes/protr.html) package just came out, which has a parallelized pairwise similarity scoring function, `parGOsim()`. It can take lists of protein sequences, so a loop wouldn't be necessary to write.