# R: how to write a loop to get a matrix?

Tags: r, for-loop

Thanks to the wonderful solution suggested by diliop for my previous question.

[How to get pair-wise "sequence similarity score" for ~1000 proteins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6529675/how-to-get-pair-wise-sequence-similarity-score-for-1000-proteins)

To build upon this answer, I tried to write a loop to get all the pair-wise "sequence similarity score" for 1000 proteins with the following code.

```
for (i in 1:1000){
score <- score(pairwiseAlignment(seqs[[i]]$seq, seqs[[i+1]]$seq, substitutionMatrix=BLOSUM100, gapOpening=0, gapExtension=-5))}
```

However,  it is very difficult for me to convert each score to a `data.frame`, like this that list out all the score automatically?

```
seq1 seq2 score
seq1 seq3 score
seq1 seq4 score
....
seq1000 seq1000 score
```

Could expert give me some more hints how to get 1000 x 1000 proteins?

Comment: What is the structure (`str`) of `score`?

Comment: I interpreted the request as how to build a data.frame that calculated `score` from the values of `seq1` and `seq2` using the function, `score(pairwiseAlignment(...))`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to improve this code for getting pairwise ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6543167/how-to-improve-this-code-for-getting-pairwise)

Answer (score 5):

This appears to be a task that you can do with expand.grid and apply:

```
seqs <-c("seq1","seq2","seq3"); dat <- expand.grid(seqs,seqs, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
dat
apply(dat, 1, function(seq) paste(seq[1], seq[2], sep="--") )
#[1] "seq1--seq1" "seq2--seq1" "seq3--seq1" "seq1--seq2" "seq2--seq2" "seq3--seq2" "seq1--seq3"
#[8] "seq2--seq3" "seq3--seq3"
```

Admittedly there is duplication of effort if the function returns the same value for f(seq1,seq2) as for f(seq2,seq1), but if you wanted to gain efficiency you could limit the first argument to apply:

```
 datr <- dat[dat[,1] > dat[,2] , ]
```

So if you made such a restricted-row-dataframe, `datr`, then perhaps:

```
datr$score <-  apply(datr, 1 , function(seq) {
                     score(pairwiseAlignment( seq[1], seq[2], 
                     substitutionMatrix=BLOSUM100, gapOpening=0, gapExtension=-5)) }
```

(Not knowing anything about the arguments in the last line. You really should learn to put in some real data in your examples and to list the required packages with `library` or `require` calls.)