# How to improve this code for getting pairwise?

Tags: r, apply

It is a question build upon the previous question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6538448/r-how-to-write-a-loop-to-get-a-matrix).

It is different from the previous one, as more details is provided, and libraries and example file is provided according to comments from DWin.  So, I submitted it as a new question. Could you mind to teach me how to modify this code further?

To load the necessary libraries:

```
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite()
```

My protseq.fasta file has the following contents:

```
>drugbank_target|1 Peptidoglycan synthetase ftsI (DB00303)  
MVKFNSSRKSGKSKKTIRKLTAPETVKQNKPQKVFEKCFMRGRYMLSTVLILLGLCALVARAAYVQSINADTLSNEADKR
SLRKDEVLSVRGSILDRNGQLLSVSVPMSAIVADPKTMLKENSLADKERIAALAEELGMTENDLVKKIEKNSKSGYLYLA
RQVELSKANYIRRLKIKGIILETEHRRFYPRVEEAAHVVGYTDIDGNGIEGIEKSFNSLLVGKDGSRTVRKDKRGNIVAH
ISDEKKYDAQDVTLSIDEKLQSMVYREIKKAVSENNAESGTAVLVDVRTGEVLAMATAPSYNPNNRVGVKSELMRNRAIT
DTFEPGSTVKPFVVLTALQRGVVKRDEIIDTTSFKLSGKEIVDVAPRAQQTLDEILMNSSNRGVSRLALRMPPSALMETY
QNAGLSKPTDLGLIGEQVGILNANRKRWADIERATVAYGYGITATPLQIARAYATLGSFGVYRPLSITKVDPPVIGKRVF
SEKITKDIVGILEKVAIKNKRAMVEGYRVGVKTGTARKIENGHYVNKYVAFTAGIAPISDPRYALVVLINDPKAGEYYGG
AVSAPVFSNIMGYALRANAIPQDAEAAENTTTKSAKRIVYIGEHKNQKVN
>drugbank_target|3 Histidine decarboxylase (DB00114; DB00117)  
MMEPEEYRERGREMVDYICQYLSTVRERRVTPDVQPGYLRAQLPESAPEDPDSWDSIFGDIERIIMPGVVHWQSPHMHAY
YPALTSWPSLLGDMLADAINCLGFTWASSPACTELEMNVMDWLAKMLGLPEHFLHHHPSSQGGGVLQSTVSESTLIALLA
ARKNKILEMKTSEPDADESCLNARLVAYASDQAHSSVEKAGLISLVKMKFLPVDDNFSLRGEALQKAIEEDKQRGLVPVF
VCATLGTTGVCAFDCLSELGPICAREGLWLHIDAAYAGTAFLCPEFRGFLKGIEYADSFTFNPSKWMMVHFDCTGFWVKD
KYKLQQTFSVNPIYLRHANSGVATDFMHWQIPLSRRFRSVKLWFVIRSFGVKNLQAHVRHGTEMAKYFESLVRNDPSFEI
PAKRHLGLVVFRLKGPNCLTENVLKEIAKAGRLFLIPATIQDKLIIRFTVTSQFTTRDDILRDWNLIRDAATLILSQHCT
SQPSPRVGNLISQIRGARAWACGTSLQSVSGAGDDPVQARKIIKQPQRVGAGPMKRENGLHLETLLDPVDDCFSEEAPDA
TKHKLSSFLFSYLSVQTKKKTVRSLSCNSVPVSAQKPLPTEASVKNGGSSRVRIFSRFPEDMMMLKKSAFKKLIKFYSVP
SFPECSSQCGLQLPCCPLQAMV
>drugbank_target|5 Glutaminase liver isoform, mitochondrial (DB00130; DB00142)  
MRSMKALQKALSRAGSHCGRGGWGHPSRSPLLGGGVRHHLSEAAAQGRETPHSHQPQHQDHDSSESGMLSRLGDLLFYTI
AEGQERTPIHKFTTALKATGLQTSDPRLRDCMSEMHRVVQESSSGGLLDRDLFRKCVSSSIVLLTQAFRKKFVIPDFEEF
TGHVDRIFEDVKELTGGKVAAYIPQLAKSNPDLWGVSLCTVDGQRHSVGHTKIPFCLQSCVKPLTYAISISTLGTDYVHK
FVGKEPSGLRYNKLSLDEEGIPHNPMVNAGAIVVSSLIKMDCNKAEKFDFVLQYLNKMAGNEYMGFSNATFQSEKETGDR
NYAIGYYHEEKKCFPKGVDMMAALDLYFQLCSVEVTCESGSVMAATLANGGICPITGESVLSAEAVRNTLSLMHSCGMYD
FSGQFAFHVGLPAKSAVSGAILLVVPNVMGMMCLSPPLDKLGNSHRGTSFCQKLVSLFNFHNYDNLRHCARKLDPRREGA
EIRNKTVVNLLFAAYSGDVSALRRFALSAMDMEQKDYDSRTALHVAAAEGHIEVVKFLIEACKVNPFAKDRWGNIPLDDA
VQFNHLEVVKLLQDYQDSYTLSETQAEAAAEALSKENLESMV
>drugbank_target|6 Coagulation factor XIII A chain (DB00130; DB01839; DB02340)  
SETSRTAFGGRRAVPPNNSNAAEDDLPTVELQGVVPRGVNLQEFLNVTSVHLFKERWDTNKVDHHTDKYENNKLIVRRGQ
SFYVQIDFSRPYDPRRDLFRVEYVIGRYPQENKGTYIPVPIVSELQSGKWGAKIVMREDRSVRLSIQSSPKCIVGKFRMY
VAVWTPYGVLRTSRNPETDTYILFNPWCEDDAVYLDNEKEREEYVLNDIGVIFYGEVNDIKTRSWSYGQFEDGILDTCLY
VMDRAQMDLSGRGNPIKVSRVGSAMVNAKDDEGVLVGSWDNIYAYGVPPSAWTGSVDILLEYRSSENPVRYGQCWVFAGV
FNTFLRCLGIPARIVTNYFSAHDNDANLQMDIFLEEDGNVNSKLTKDSVWNYHCWNEAWMTRPDLPVGFGGWQAVDSTPQ
ENSDGMYRCGPASVQAIKHGHVCFQFDAPFVFAEVNSDLIYITAKKDGTHVVENVDATHIGKLIVTKQIGGDGMMDITDT
YKFQEGQEEERLALETALMYGAKKPLNTEGVMKSRSNVDMDFEVENAVLGKDFKLSITFRNNSHNRYTITAYLSANITFY
TGVPKAEFKKETFDVTLEPLSFKKEAVLIQAGEYMGQLLEQASLHFFVTARINETRDVLAKQKSTVLTIPEIIIKVRGTQ
VVGSDMTVTVQFTNPLKETLRNVWVHLDGPGVTRPMKKMFREIRPNSTVQWEEVCRPWVSGHRKLIASMSSDSLRHVYGE
LDVQIQRRPSM
```

To load the data to R for the analysis, I have done:

```
require("Biostrings")
data(BLOSUM100)
seqs <- readFASTA("./protseq.fasta", strip.descs=TRUE)
```

To get the the pairwise numbers, as there are a total of 4 sequences, I have done:

```
number <-c(1:4); dat <- expand.grid(number,number, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
datr <- dat[dat[,1] > dat[,2] , ]
```

In order to calculate the score one by one, I can do this:

```
 score(pairwiseAlignment(seqs[[x]]$seq, seqs[[y]]$seq, substitutionMatrix=BLOSUM100, gapOpening=0, gapExtension=-5))
```

However, I have problem to add a new column as "score" to include all the score for each pairs of the proteins.  I tried to do this, but did not work.

```
datr$score <- lapply(datr, 1, function(i) { x <- datr[i,1]; y<- datr[i,2]; score(pairwiseAlignment(seqs[[x]]$seq, seqs[[y]]$seq, substitutionMatrix=BLOSUM100, gapOpening=0, gapExtension=-5))})
```

Could you mind to comments how to further improve it?  Thanks DWin and diliop for wonderful solutions to my previous question.

Comment: OMG, I read it as drunk bank. Time to go to bed... Good question BTW, +1!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
datr$score <- sapply(1:nrow(datr), function(i) {
    x <- datr[i,1]
    y <- datr[i,2]
    score(pairwiseAlignment(seqs[[x]]$seq, seqs[[y]]$seq, substitutionMatrix=BLOSUM100,gapOpening=0, gapExtension=-5))
})
```

To be able to reference your sequences better using their names, you might want to tidy up `datr` by doing the following:

```
colnames(datr) <- c("seq1id", "seq2id", "score")
datr$seq1name <- sapply(datr$seq1id, function(i) seqs[[i]]$desc)
datr$seq2name <- sapply(datr$seq2id, function(i) seqs[[i]]$desc)
```

Or if you just want to extract the accession IDs i.e. the contents of your parentheses, you could use `stringr` as such:

```
library(stringr)
datr$seq1name <- sapply(datr$seq2id, function(i) str_extract(seqs[[i]]$desc, "DB[0-9\\ ;DB]+"))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you @diliop.  I can get it works now.  Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm just guessing, but would OPs code work if he `unlist`ed his lapply result?